# Limit of double integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Let $A \subset [0, 1]$ be a measurable set and $I \subset [0, 1]$ an interval. Find the limit of

$$ k \int_A\int_I (1-|x-y|)^kdxdy $$

as $k \to \infty$.

I suppose one has to do some fiddling with Fubini-Tonelli but I am not sure what.